# jQuery only works if I hard code it into the html.tpl.php

Tags: theming, javascript

Running into this issue where my custom jQuery code only works in my drupal theme if I end up adding `<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>` in the `<head>` tag of the `html.tpl.php` file.

I tried all the other ways via template, info and still none of them work other then doing this.

Suggestions?

Thanks,

.-C

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. Requires one to enclose all jQuery scripts with:

(function($){

\\  Enter script here ///

})(jQuery)

Answer (score 0):

Drupal core ships with jQuery. You can check the version in your `<drupal_install_directory>/misc/jquery.js` file. If you want to use the later version of the library, you need to install the [jQuery Update](http://drupal.org/project/jquery_update) module.

> Upgrades the version of jQuery in Drupal core to a newer version of jQuery.
>   Updates...
>
> - Drupal 5 to jQuery 1.2.6
> - Drupal 6 to jQuery 1.3.2
> - Drupal 7 to jQuery 1.5.2/1.7.1/1.8.2, and jQuery UI 1.8.11

Comment: Yeah have that module installed an using 1.8.

Comment: I had used "Save Form State Module" in a recent project, and it worked fine for me using the jQuery update module.